# VCL Components not rendering pretty Windows styles

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

My delphi application looks nice and pretty in the editor, but when compiled it's seemed to being using super old rendering for the buttons and stuff. I thought my compiled applications used to look pretty like the editor.  What could I have screwed up for this to be happening?

One suspicion: a while back I was messing with manifests on a different app that needed to find the actual program files directory.  Could I have screwed up my delphi project trying too hard for that?  This project is set to use runtime themes.

The top is in the editor, the bottom is the compiled version
[image: The top is in the editor, the bottom is the compiled version]

Comment: If you played around with manifests, then remove any manifest that you've added. Sounds like that's the key issue, because by default all Delphi apps use runtime themes. Even with that enabled though, the manifest overrides it all.

Comment: But is there somewhere I could have put a global manifest that would affect other projects?  This project has no manifest in it's directory.  I only recall creating one for the project and telling that project to use a custom manifest.  Anything else stupid I could have done with them?

Comment: Wait, so this happens on all of your projects?

Comment: No, turns out just this one.  But it doesn't have a custom manifest, though I may have attempted it in the past.  Is there some other way I could have disabled VCL styles or an old manifest been stuck with it?

Comment: Also check compatibility settings.

Comment: Go to `Project > Resources and Images`, and see if anything is listed there.

Comment: Nothing under resources and images.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Where are compatibility settings?

Comment: Right click on the executable in explorer. Select properties, then compatibility.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I'm just running it from the IDE.

Comment: If you want to check compatibility settings (I'd suggest doing so, it's one probable reason visual themes are not used), right click on the executable in explorer, select properties, then compatibility.

Comment: Are you sure you have set the application options of your project properly and is compiled with the correct manifest file? See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Application_Options

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I just checked the executable in the output directory, and it isn't running in compatibility mode.  Deleting and recompiling doesn't change things.

Comment: @StefanGlienke Under application options it says "Use Runtime Themes" and custom manifest is grayed out.  Under appearance the default style is Windows.

Comment: You did rebuild of course?

Comment: Yes I did. more chars

Comment: Check your project and source files for resource directives (`{$R }`) that contain something other than `{$R *.res}`, which would indicate a custom resource file. It may contain a manifest.

Comment: Open the compiled executable in a resource editor and check if a manifest resource did get compiled into it. If so, that manifest is likely missing the theme elements, like if you enabled a custom/3rd-party UAC manifest. There can only be one manifest, so it has to have everything in it.

Comment: Just the `{$R *.dfm}` from a form and a data module.

Comment: @EricG Like Remy said, are you using any third-party libraries or units?

Comment: There is one third party library, but if I comment out that code and the `uses` call to include it, I don't get any difference. Of course there are still several installed in Delphi.  I will load up a resource editor tomorrow and also try compiling at a co-workers desk to see if I've just screwed up something locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is being rendered without themes. Possible causes for that:

1. Your executable has no manifest.
2. Your executable has a manifest, but it does not specify v6 comctl32.
3. Your manifest does specify v6 comctl32 but the process is using an external compatibility mode.
4. Your program disables visual styles in code. For example with a call to `SetThemeAppProperties`.
5. Your program uses activation contexts to activate a different manifest from that linked to the executable.

These possibilities get progressively more far-fetched. Most likely you've somehow fluffed your manifest. That's easy to check with a resource editor.

Comment: The winner is no manifest whatsoever.  Any reason why?  It was set to use runtime themes, but even when I set it to Use Custom Manifest, and copy the default manifest to use in the directory, it still compiles with no manifest.

Comment: Found it.  In my project file `{$R *.res}` had been changed to `{R *.res}` and I have no idea how.  Thanks.